# Silverlight for WP7: Trim an existing media file

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

WP7 Mango is making it possible to save custom ringtones from apps. That's great and all, but not if your source material is too long in length (ringtones must be < 40 seconds or so).

I'm hoping it is possible to take an existing audio file (wma, lets say) and trim it by setting a start/end point, so you can export just a part of the audio for ringtone use.

I gather from other SO questions that audio encoding directly in silverlight is not really feasible. But I don't really want full encoding capabilities, just the ability to trim an existing already encoded file. Any pointers?

Comment: You are probably going to need a library that can decode the file into an uncompressed stream, cut it up, the encode it again. If you can not find one for the Silverlight framework, have you considered making it a web service?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that... upvote for you. But it would be costly in bandwidth to upload an entire song and return a part of it, not to mention slow. This is a free app from a hobby developer, hosting a service for it is a last resort... I hope.

Comment: Have you thought about extending the library for the ringtone so that you can display a full song, no limit to the length?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I can't extend the phone's native ringtone capabilities. The 40 second limit is part of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about doing this as well (until I discovered that we have no access to the music already on the phone).

An mp3 should be pretty easy to do by checking the header (see here: http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm) and then using the bit rate and frame size to calculate the number of bytes to copy using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter.

I haven't looked into wma but after glancing over the specifications it looks like it may be more complicated (specs: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14995).

Comment: Very helpful reply... let me know if you figure it out :)

Comment: Has anyone already solved this problem for mp3 or do I need to calculate the math myself and byte headers?

Comment: Sorry Bob, I haven't looked into this since I posted. The lack of access to the media library put an end to my app concept...